# A want a software visits a url from multiple proxies automatic and send data using POST Method

Tags: post, proxy, automation, http-post

I want to suggest me a software visits a url from multiple proxies automatic and send data using POST Method ( The value of the POST Variables must be everytime different). For example the first time will be "Dim Ra" The second time will be "something else". I want these variables can loaded via a text file. If someone can suggest me a software or create it for me. I will pay of-course 
....I need a software like i-Fake but with the ability to give every time different value of the variables loaded from a txt file....
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer these two posts: http://irobotsoft.org/bb/YaBB.pl?num=1299171620 and 
http://irobotsoft.org/bb/YaBB.pl?num=1299263664/0